# Excel use Wildcards in LOOKUP RANGE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know one can use wildcards as following

```
A1&"*"
```

But is it possible to use the wildcards and return a range/array? Sort of like:

```
A1&"*":A4&"*"
```

Table1

```
columnA    columnB
John123    ?
John243    ?
John422    ?
```

Table2

```
columnA    columnB
John       Smith
```

The goal is to have a MATCH function in Table1 ColumnB that will pull in the value from Table2 ColumnB where the ColumnA's both start with John.

I would like to try something like this to get Table1 ColumnB values

```
= MATCH( A1 ; Table2!A1:A3 &"*")
```

Comment: can you eleborate? it's slightly unclear what you need.

Comment: what should be returned if `Table 2` Column `A` has values: `Jo` and `John`?

Comment: There will not be any similar values in the table, so I won't worry about it.

Comment: Is it possible to use a custom VBA-function to do what you want?

Comment: I figured it would be, but I'm not familiar with VBA, and thought that this might be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself eventually:

```
{=MATCH(A1;table2!$A$1:$A:$4&"*")}
```

Make sure to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when entering.